# Li-Ion Rechargeable 2032 Button 3.6V Cell and Arduino

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, lipo

I have designed a battery powered Arduino device. The on-off switch connects the battery to the circuit. When the user plug USB cable while the switch is on, the battery and the circuit directly get 5V. I decided to use a low loss diode to protect the battery from USB voltage, but it empties the battery very fast.
I know I can use pfet also. Is there any other idea? Connecting 5v directly to Li-Ion Rechargeable battery is dangerous?
[image: schema]

Answer (score 1):

Application of 5V directly on a Li-ion battery will overcharge and damage the battery at least, and at most will cause overheating or fire.  You will want to charge a 3.6 volt battery with a constant current until it reaches 4.2 volts, then hold the voltage here.
Your low loss diode is likely not what is draining your battery.  Cells of this size are designed to provide currents under 1 milliamp for hundreds of hours, but they don't like high currents; at tens of milliamps, you will see the voltage drop in seconds, although the battery may recover if the voltage is removed.  If your load is down in the milliamp range and your battery is still draining quickly, it is likely damaged.

Comment: Thanks, John, Because of very limited space and need of 3,6v I choose 2032 coin type battery. Is there an other option that form fit that place?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13852